# chef recipe to start weblogic adminserver

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I've installed weblogic. Now I want to start the adminserver. The below starts the adminserver but chef is still running. When I come out of the terminal, it shuts down the server also. How can I run the below in the background & exit chef successfully after this step. Please help.

```
execute "Starting admin server" do
  user user
  group group
  command "sh #{domain_home}/startWebLogic.sh"
  action :run  
end
```

Comment: You may find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604358/starting-weblogic-server-in-background-in-linux

Comment: Thanks. Based on the link, I did the below, chef continues but the server is not started. What am I doing wrong. execute "Starting admin server" do
  user user
  group group
  #command "sh #{domain_home}/startWebLogic.sh"
  command "sh nohup #{domain_home}/startWebLogic.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
  action :run
  
end

Comment: Is there a way to wait till it gets started & exit chef?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead to fully background the server process and allow Chef to finish:

```
command "nohup #{domain_home}/startWebLogic.sh &>/dev/null &"
```

You should then be able to either see the server process running or go check your admin server .out log file to see what has happened.

Comment: I realized my mistake. it works. Is there a way to wait till the server gets started after invoking the startWebLogic.sh

Comment: There are other options. For instance you could write a `wlst` script like mentioned here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13708/overview.htm#START118 And that script can block until the server comes up. But just running `startWebLogic` - no, there is no way for Chef to know when the script has reached running. You could add another Chef step that monitors a log file for `RUNNING` as well

Answer (score 0):

You could append the commnd with "&" to send it to background or nohup as answered earlier.

However, the ideal way to handle this would be to write a simple start/stop script for  initd/upstart/monit/runit. That would handle this gracefully. Some systems also come with [start-stop-daemon](http://man.he.net/man8/start-stop-daemon) tools which would help you manage those.